# C# Windows Form - How make Textbox array variable?

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox, runtime, repeat

```
int iAcessorioContar = 10;
for (int iContador = 2; iContador <= iAcessorioContar; iContador++)
                {
                    Label lblAcessorio = (Label)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("lblAcessorio" + iContador, false).FirstOrDefault();
                    TextBox txtAcessorio = (TextBox)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("txtAcessorio" + iContador, false).FirstOrDefault();
                }
```

I would like to store in variables lblAcessorio and txtAcessorio array all textbox and labels values, this way i can refer than in my code (all these labels and textbox will be created in runtime, because of this i need this.

Thanks

Comment: You can do this anyway?

Comment: not understood what you said ?

Comment: Based on what you wrote you are trying to store buttons in lists to access them but you can access them anyway

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking how to put what you're getting into an array. So, here is some code showing how to use an array which should point you in the right direction.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GenericTest()
    {
        object[,] array = new object[9, 2];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            array[i, 0] = i;
            array[i, 1] = i * 2;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < array.GetLength(1); k++)
            {
                Console.Write(array[i,k]+" ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

> 0 0
>
> 1 2
>
> 2 4
>
> 3 6
>
> 4 8
>
> 5 10
>
> 6 12
>
> 7 14
>
> 8 16

Answer (score 0):

Create Lists and add them:

```
        // declare these at CLASS level (not in the method that has the code below)
        List<Label> Labels = new List<Label>();
        List<TextBox> TextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

        ...
            // in some method:
            int iAcessorioContar = 10;
            for (int iContador = 2; iContador <= iAcessorioContar; iContador++)
            {
                Label lblAcessorio = (Label)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("lblAcessorio" + iContador, false).FirstOrDefault();
                TextBox txtAcessorio = (TextBox)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("txtAcessorio" + iContador, false).FirstOrDefault();

                Labels.Add(lblAcessorio);
                TextBoxes.Add(txtAcessorio);
            }
```